# Use of word DOWN

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, differences

Why do we use word DOWN with some verbs. What difference does it make? 
e.g. 'I am writing it' or 'I am writing it down'. 
Track it or Track it down etc.

Comment: Well, if you were "writing it up" you'd be a cop writing a traffic ticket.

Comment: If there are no solid rules for the construction of phrases with *down*, then the correct answer is "There are no solid rules for construction of phrases with *down*." This question should not have been closed.

Comment: Curious about what difference does it make to use 'down' with some verbs!!  
more examples: burn down, calm down, call down, cool down etc.

Answer (score 1):

*track it down* is an idiom that means to search for something. *track it* means to follow the tracks that something left.

There's not much difference between *write it* and *write it down*.

I don't think there's a general answer, many of these uses are idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a general answer to your question, but a difference between A: "I wrote what he said" and B: "I wrote down what he said" is that A could mean he told me to write certain things, and I did write them.  B could mean that, too, but it could also mean that I wrote down the words that he spoke, perhaps without him even knowing about it.

Comment: I think this is the completive _down_: _Let me get their shipping changes down straight, before I start thinking about our own schedules._ The metaphor can be "swallowing/stomaching", "down on paper/recorded", "down and dirty, ready for action", or several others, but they point at completion and competence in general. This is probly part of the `Down Is Concrete` aspect of [the `Up/Down` theme](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) -- Feet on the Ground/Head in the Air.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that *down* in *writing it down* and *tracking it down* are two different things. Since Greg hit on the writing part already, I'll leave it alone.
Tracking, running, or touching things *down* gives a sense of completion that  isn't present when you're just tracking, running, and touching.

The *down* is being used in the same sense as bottom in "Get to the bottom of this!"

An alternative for *track it down* in cases like this could be *track it all the way*

Answer (score 0):

Down can be used literally (as in ascent/descent), eg falling down, climb down etc or as a metaphor.  'down' is used for prescriptive actions (usually multiple things ordered in list), eg. jot down the points, worth noting in this movie.  I am writing down the members of the team.